# Kotlin/Android – KotlinReflectionInternalError in Data Class with a lambda

Tags: exception, reflection, lambda, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

> kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError:
>   Introspecting local functions, lambdas, anonymous functions and local
>   variables is not yet fully supported in Kotlin reflection

This exception comes from `toString()` of a data class.

The data class contains a lambda.

I can't reproduce it in my environment.

Do I need to override `toString()` to exclude the lambda? Or lambdas are not allowed in data classes at all?

```
data class PersistJob(
        private val id: Int,
        private val delay: Long = 10_000L,
        private val maxDelay: Long = 60_000L,
        private val iteration: Int = 0,
        private val block: suspend (Int) -> Boolean) {

    fun getDelay() = minOf(delay, maxDelay)
    fun withDelayIncreased() = copy(
            delay = minOf(delay * 2, maxDelay),
            iteration = iteration + 1)

    suspend fun execute() = block(iteration)
}
```

Line producing the error:

```
val job: PersistJob = ...
log.debug("start job id($id): $job")`// job.toString()
```

Stack trace:

```
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.EmptyContainerForLocal.fail(SourceFile:41)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.EmptyContainerForLocal.getFunctions(SourceFile:37)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl.findFunctionDescriptor(SourceFile:145)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$descriptor$2.invoke(SourceFile:54)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$descriptor$2.invoke(SourceFile:34)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(SourceFile:93)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(SourceFile:32)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl.getDescriptor(SourceFile)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl.renderLambdaToString(SourceFile:59)
at kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection.renderLambdaToString(SourceFile:80)
at kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda.toString(SourceFile:22)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2683)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:129)
```

Comment: `I can't reproduce it in my environment` - how come?

Comment: Via crash reports.

Comment: I believe this error shows when android device is below 6.0. had the same issue App worked on device 6.0 and above but not in 5.0. i believe its a bug from Kotlin

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19186

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug in Kotlin lambdas.

This code is enough to reproduce the exception:

```
 ({i: Int -> true}).toString()
```

I advice you post an issue on youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT and see what the team says about it.

Comment: What's your environment? It works well on mine `Kotlin version 1.1.51 (JRE 1.8.0_144-b01)`

Comment: Yeah. And `System.getProperty("java.version")` returns `1.8.0_45`. So it seems not a problem of Java version.